# How to Start an Intent from a contained class of an Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-context

I'm looking for the best way to start an intent from a class that is not an Activity, but is a contained object of an Activity class.

For example the Activity Class:

```
Class MainActivity extends ListActivty
{
...
TestLauncher tester;
}
```

and the class that I want to start the intent from:

```
Class TestLauncher
{
   public TestLauncher ()
   {
      //Code to create an intent needs a Context
      //Intent i = new Intent(Context, class)

      //Code to start activity needs to be called with an Activity
      //Activity.StartActivity(i);
   }
}
```

What is the best way to do this architecturally? Should I pass `MainActivity` as a parameter to `TestLauncher`'s constructor? Or is there a better way that I am not aware of?

Comment: @J J: "Should I pass MainActivity as a paramter to TestLauncher's constructor?" - Yes, either that or simply pass `this` as a one-off to whatever method in `TestLauncher` is used to start the activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Class TestLauncher
{
   public TestLauncher (Context c)
   {
      Intent i = new Intent(c, YourActivity.class)
      c.startActivity(i);
   }
}

TestLauncher ts=new TestLauncher(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Don't use `getApplicationContext()`. Just pass `this` (being the Activity Context). Using `getApplicationContext()` might cause unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Couldn't passing Activity context cause memory leaks?

Comment: Hmmm, tricky one. Yes, in some cases passing an Activity context can cause leaks but in the case of the OP's question with the inner class being used to simply start another activity, it's being used just for that. Good point - I take back what I said, using application context is probably as valid but I tend not to use it unless I specifically need it.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about getApplicationContext().
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Follow up question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351181/how-to-start-an-intent-for-result-from-a-contained-class-of-an-activity-startact