# How to Start an Intent for Result from a contained class of an Activity (startActivityForResult)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-context

This is a follow up to my previous question:
[How to Start an Intent from a contained class of an Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337135/how-to-start-an-intent-from-a-contained-class-of-an-activity)

Basically, I realized that I need to call `startActivityForResult` (and not `startActivity`) from a contained class of an Activity. The answer from the previous question passed the Context from the Activity class to the contained class. However, the context alone isn't enough to call `StartActivityForResult`.

What is the best way to do this? Do I have to pass the entire Activity Class to the method in the contained class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Pass your Activity to the contained class as a parameter.

P.S. Do NOT store the reference to the Activity. Pass it in as you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, looking at your question, you should be able to do this:

```
Class TestLauncher
{
   public TestLauncher (Context c)
   {
      Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourActivity.class)
      MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(i, 1);
   }
}
```

Try that and see if it works.

Comment: From his other question I don't think the "contained" class is actually a contained inner class. It's a separate class, and the Activity has an instance of that class contained in it. Confusing and inaccurate wording, but I think that's the case we're dealing with.

Comment: Ah. Then passing it in is probably the way forward.

Comment: @LeffelMania - You're right, that is what I meant... What is the correct terminology for an object that is a member of the main class (so I don't confuse people in the future)?

Comment: So... what is the point of passing in "Context c" if you never use it?

Also, trying to do "MainActivity.this", I get a compile time error: "No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope". I assume this is because TestLauncher is not a nested class?

Comment: I'd assumed it was nested. If it is just a regular class then you should probably do what @LeffelMania recommended and pass in your Activity instance as a method parameter.